# How to get reference to static class of Java super class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-java-interop

I've got sample third party Java code:

```java
public class ApiClass extends PackagePrivateClass {
}

abstract class PackagePrivateClass {
    public static class StaticClass {
    }
}
```

So only `ApiClass` and `StaticClass` are public. In Java I can get reference to `StaticClass` with: `ApiClass.StaticClass`. For the same code in Kotlin I got `Unresolved reference: StaticClass`. I can't also get reference via `PackagePrivateClass`, because it's package private (captain obvious). Is there any hack to get reference to `StaticClass` (it's third party code so I can't simply make PackagePrivateClass `public`)?

I understand that it's probably 'by design', however it forbids me from using 3p code

Comment: Have you tried kotlin reflection, https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/member-references-and-reflection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only solution is to build Java wrapper class that your kotlin class can access to.

```
public class ApiClass extends PackagePrivateClass {

}

abstract class PackagePrivateClass {

    public static class StaticClass {

        void instanceFunction() {

        }

        static void classFunction() {
        }
    }
}
```

The adapter java class (StaticClassAdapter.java):

```
class StaticClassAdapter {

    private static ApiClass.StaticClass staticClass;

    void instanceFunction() {
        staticClass.instanceFunction();
    }

    static void classFunction() {
        PackagePrivateClass.StaticClass.classFunction();
    }
}
```

So in your kotlin code...

```
class KotlinClass {

    fun main() {
        StaticClassAdapter().instanceFunction()
        StaticClassAdapter.classFunction()
    }
}
```